# iOS Firebase -When Fanning Out -'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm fanning out to send data to different refs. When I first post the below code everything works fine. I then go to repost the code again using the same exact postId and again it works fine.

```
let root: DatabaseReference!
let uid = gHcqsRzK0xZJ3Zp11xAikDTKIKw2 // Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

root = Database.database().reference()

let postId = "123"
let postsRef = "posts/\(uid)/\(postId)"
let usesrRef = "users/\(uid)/\(postId)"

let dict = [String: Any]()
dict.updateValue(someOtherDict, forKey: postsRef)
dict.updateValue(someOtherDict, forKey: usersRef)

root.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: { [weak self] (error, ref) in
```

However when I try the same exact code and append an additional child to the fan out refs, the first time everything works fine and the second time when I try to repost again I keep getting an error

> 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string
>   and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

```
let postId = "123"
let additionalUid = "456"
let postsRef = "posts/\(uid)/\(postId)/\(additionalUid)"
let usesrRef = "users/\(uid)/\(postId)/\(additionalUid)"
```

I've been checking for hours (print statements and debugger) and the uid nor the postId nor the additionalUid contains any of the invalid characters.

**Why does this problem only occur when fanning out and appending an additional child to the ref?**

Answer (score 0):

Try and fix your uid to looks something like this

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid else { return }
```

Comment: I've been checking for hours it's not my uid and even if it was it would crash because it's forcefully unwrapped. I forgot to add the uid part

Comment: May I recommend that you copy and paste the actual, complete, minimal code into the question rather than some estimation of it.  Hard code as many values as possible.

Comment: @DougStevenson it's a ton of code because the dictionary has multiple values (I've checked them all) and there are 3 other refs. I commented everything unnecessary out and put in the actual foo  values you see above ("123" and "456") and it only crashes when I add those values or whatever variation of them. Once I remove them it works fine. Its odd because it only happens with them.

Comment: @LuisFRamirez I forgot to add it in the question, inside my actual code it's there. Its not the uid because it wouldn't never work. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @LanceSamaria No problem that you forgot to add something to your question. Click the `edit` link under it, and add the hardcoded UID with which you can reproduce the problem. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints. Having a standalone reproduction will make it *much* more likely that one of us will spot what is going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok thanks. I’ll make a separate project and then see what happens and upload the code. Thanks for the advice. It’ll be ready in the am.